# CSS: Cell border isn't rounded for some reason

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I want to make a nice navigation bar, but for some reason, I can't get the borders of the cells on the ends of the bar to be rounded. If you look closely at the corners, you should be able to see a bit of rounding happening to the background, but not to the border for some reason.

You can see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/7veZQ/299/

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #BBB;
}
.nav tr td {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.nav tr td:hover {
    background: #F4F4F4; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%, #E0E0E0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F4F4F4), color-stop(100%,#E0E0E0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* W3C */
}
.nav tr td#first {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.nav tr td#last {
    color: #09C;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="nav" width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="first">Home</td>
    <td>Options</td>
    <td>Prices</td>
    <td>Showcase</td>
    <td>Help</td>
    <td id="last">Order Now!</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend you build your navigation menu using `div` elements as opposed to a table.  Tables shouldn't be used for layout, even something as simple as a nav menu.  Divs are less finicky than tables, too, which may solve your rounded-corner issue.

Answer (score 4):

> So what am I doing wrong?

Using a table for layout.

[Tables are not layout tools](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/). Some browsers won't round corners on table cells. You have a list of data, [use list markup](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/%5D).

Comment: The irony being that this very post is a `<td>` in a `<table>` that is laying out this whole page (although I agree it shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1):

change your table css to

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not cross browser CSS. CSS3 is not found in all browsers. That being said, there are a few changes I'd suggest. First, you shouldn't really use exact heights & widths for anything.

Second, you should be using DIVs.
[Decent forum post as to why...](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?721289-Why-Switch-from-Table-to-CSS-layout)

In any case, here is the "fix" (I'm personally against floating anything, but oh well. It is what happens sometimes:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.nav {
    float:left;
    width:960px;
    height:40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #BBB;
}
.nav a {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background: #F4F4F4; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%, #E0E0E0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F4F4F4), color-stop(100%,#E0E0E0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F4F4F4 0%,#E0E0E0 100%); /* W3C */
}
.nav a#first {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.nav a#last {
    color: #09C;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-menu" class="nav">
    <a href="#" id="first">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Options</a>
    <a href="#">Prices</a>
    <a href="#">Showcase</a>
    <a href="#">Help</a>
    <a href="#" id="last">Order Now!</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This should be all you need for it to work... If you are having trouble with CSS Layouts, check out YUI3 Grids. I'm a fan of YUI 3, so yes, this is a shameful plug.

[YUI Library](http://yuilibrary.com)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7veZQ/313/

The table is converted into `div` + `ul`.

Look at `line-height` (used here to center the text vertically).

Also, I changed `first` and `last` to be `classes` (instead of `id's`) as they are very common names and `id's` should be unique in document.

At last, look at the `borders`. We don't have `border-collapse` in lists so the `last` item is a little different than the others.